# jQuery divide and multiple give the wrong answer

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form below where a user inputs something on the fields and the other fields will be filled automatically with the formula. However, it seems like jQuery is giving the wrong calculation and read the input values as a string, which could possibly be the reason why it is giving a wrong calculation.

I've been looking for solution but `parseInt` and `Number()` doesn't seem to work.

Or maybe I did it wrong.

Check the snippet below, if you type 5, 10, and 20. It gives 1.9 and 190 instead of 2.4 and 240 (the correct answers).

```js
$('form').on('change', 'input[type="number"]', validate);
nutrition = $('input[name="nutrition"]').val();
carbs = $('input[name="carbs"]').val();
proteins = $('input[name="proteins"]').val();
fats = $('input[name="fats"]').val();
validate();

function validate() {
  if (($('input[name="nutrition"]').val() != "") &&
    ($('input[name="carbs"]').val() != "") &&
    ($('input[name="proteins"]').val() != "") &&
    ($('input[name="fats"]').val() != "")) {

    var nutrition = $('input[name="nutrition"]').val();
    var carbs = $('input[name="carbs"]').val();
    var proteins = $('input[name="proteins"]').val();
    var fats = $('input[name="fats"]').val();

    $('input[name="tcarbs"]').val(carbs / nutrition);
    $('input[name="tproteins"]').val(proteins / nutrition);
    $('input[name="tfats"]').val(fats / nutrition);

    var unitcalories = (Number(carbs) / Number(nutrition) * 4) + (Number(proteins) / Number(nutrition) * 4) + (Number(fats) / Number(nutrition) * 9);

    var tcalories = Number(unitcalories) * Number(nutrition);
    $('input[name="calories"]').val(unitcalories);
    $('input[name="tcalories"]').val(tcalories);

  } else {
    $('input[name="tcarbs"]').val('');
    $('input[name="tproteins"]').val('');
    $('input[name="tfats"]').val('');

  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>


<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nutrition Chart Serving Size</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nutrition" value="100" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" placeholder="Serving Size">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Net Carbs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="proteins" placeholder="Net Carbs" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Proteins</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="fats" placeholder="Proteins" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Total Fats</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="carbs" placeholder="Total Fats" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Unit Calories</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="calories" placeholder="Unit Calories" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="tproteins" placeholder="" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="tfats" placeholder="" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="tcarbs" placeholder="" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="tcalories" placeholder="kCal / Serving Size" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: View the snippet in full screen. Thank you to whoever will help!

Comment: I moved jQuery BEFORE your bootstrap as it should be in your snippet

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant this

DRY: Don't repeat yourself

Also make sure the fields you have match the names of your vars

I removed the inline limitation on 0-500 and used min/max with enforcement but only on fields the user can type in

I also removed the required on the readonly

```js
function validate() {

  const nutrition = +$('input[name="nutrition"]').val(),
    carbs = +$('input[name="carbs"]').val(),
    proteins = +$('input[name="proteins"]').val(),
    fats = +$('input[name="fats"]').val();


  // or $("[type=number]").val(0); for example

  $('input[name="tcarbs"]').val('');
  $('input[name="tproteins"]').val('');
  $('input[name="tfats"]').val('');
  $('input[name="calories"]').val("");
  $('input[name="tcalories"]').val("");
console.log(nutrition,nutrition,carbs,proteins,fats)
  if (nutrition != "" && nutrition != 0 && carbs != "" && proteins && fats != "") {
    const tcarbs = carbs / nutrition;
    const tproteins = proteins / nutrition;
    const tfats = fats / nutrition;
    $('input[name="tcarbs"]').val(tcarbs.toFixed(2));
    $('input[name="tproteins"]').val(tproteins.toFixed(2));

    $('input[name="tfats"]').val(tfats.toFixed(2));

    var unitcalories = (carbs / nutrition * 4) + (proteins / nutrition * 4) + (fats / nutrition * 9);
    var tcalories = unitcalories * nutrition;
    $('input[name="calories"]').val(unitcalories.toFixed(2));
    $('input[name="tcalories"]').val(tcalories.toFixed(2));

  }
};

$(function() {
  $('form').on('change', 'input[type="number"]', validate);
  validate(); // initial run

  $('.range-enforced').on('change focus blur', function(e) {
    let min = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));
    let max = parseFloat($(this).attr('max'));
    let curr = parseFloat($(this).val());
    let changed = false;
    if (curr > max) {
      $(this).val("");
      changed = true;
    }
    if (curr < min) {
      $(this).val("");
      changed = true;
    }
    if (changed) {
      $(this).data("placeholder", $(this).attr("placeholder")); // save
      $(this).prop("placeholder", 'Only ' + min + ' through ' + max + ' allowed');
    } 
    else if ($(this).data("placeholder")) $(this).prop("placeholder", $(this).data("placeholder"));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>


<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nutrition Chart Serving Size</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control range-enforced" name="nutrition" value="100" min="0" max="500" placeholder="Serving Size">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Net Carbs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control range-enforced" name="carbs" min="0" max="500"  placeholder="Net Carbs" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Proteins</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control range-enforced" name="proteins" min="0" max="500"  placeholder="Proteins" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Fats</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control range-enforced" name="fats" min="0" max="500"  placeholder="Fats"  required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Unit Calories</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="calories" placeholder="Unit Calories" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tproteins" placeholder="" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tfats" placeholder="" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tcarbs" placeholder="" readonly>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tcalories" placeholder="kCal / Serving Size" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think it still shows the incorrect answers sir, if you input, 5, 10 and 20. The answer in Unit calories should be 2.40 or 240.

Comment: That would be up to you to write the correct formulas

Comment: The formulas are right.
If you console.log(carbs*4). Fill up the 3 inputs with different numbers, it will give an answer of 80, instead of 20.
But if you write 5,5,5 it will give 20 as answer.

Comment: I’ll look later. Not near a computer

Comment: It's solved, the problem was in HTML, thats why solutions doesnt seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesOcampo Please see update. I fixed your naming AND added min/max so no longer needed to have inline calculations for 0-500

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong names in the Inputs

Instead of:

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label>Net Carbs</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="proteins" placeholder="Net Carbs" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label>Proteins</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="fats" placeholder="Proteins" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Total Fats</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="carbs" placeholder="Total Fats" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>
```

It should be:

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label>Net Carbs</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="carbs" placeholder="Net Carbs" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
  <label>Proteins</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="proteins" placeholder="Proteins" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
  <label>Total Fats</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control " name="fats" placeholder="Total Fats" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the wrong name for each input form.

Check following:

WRONG:

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Net Carbs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="proteins" placeholder="Net Carbs" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Proteins</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="fats" placeholder="Proteins" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Total Fats</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="carbs" placeholder="Total Fats" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Unit Calories</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="calories" placeholder="Unit Calories" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
```

FIXED:

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Net Carbs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="carbs" placeholder="Net Carbs" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
      <label>Proteins</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="proteins" placeholder="Proteins" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Total Fats</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="fats" placeholder="Total Fats" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" required="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3 ">
      <label>Unit Calories</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control " name="calories" placeholder="Unit Calories" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value)>500){ this.value =500; return false; } if(parseInt(this.value)<0){ this.value =0; return false; }" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your math. Try this...

```
var unitcalories = ((Number(carbs) / Number(nutrition)) * 4) + ((Number(proteins) / Number(nutrition)) * 4) + ((Number(fats) / Number(nutrition)) * 9);
```